# HTML5 Canvas drawing multicolored lines

Tags: html, colors, canvas, line

I am trying to draw two parallel lines on the canvas, but it seems like properties of the latter overwrites the former. Please suggest what could be wrong :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="application/javascript">
  function draw() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    // draw a 10 pix green line
    ctx.strokeStyle='#00cc00';
    ctx.lineWidth=10;
    ctx.moveTo(100,0);
    ctx.lineTo(100,1000);
    ctx.stroke();
    // draw a 20 pix red line
    ctx.strokeStyle='#cc0000';
    ctx.lineWidth=20;
    ctx.moveTo(140,0);
    ctx.lineTo(140,1000);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="draw()">
    <div><canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Call `ctx.beginPath` before drawing each line. When the strong `stroke` call is made, the first line is still part of the current path so it gets drawn again in the new color.

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to draw a lot of multi-coloured lines? I'm drawing about 5000 per frame and if I make it all a single path I can run it at easy 50fps. But if I make each one an individual path so I can recolour them as I want, it chugs to 15fps. (Do you think this deserves it's own question maybe?)

Comment: @Auh Have you tried batching together lines of the same color into the same path?

Comment: Actually, after some testing I found that that if i dont have any shadowBlur on the lines, it runs perfectly fine. Now I have a different issue on my hands.